# how to use css flex to have a row of squares that scales and keeps aspect ratios?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid, responsive

I am pulling my hair out over this, I feel like it should be simple and I get close but can't get this perfect. I am trying to create a row of squares that will keep their aspect ratio but just get smaller as their container size shrinks. The way that I have gotten closest is having my square have a height of 100% with an aspect-ratio: 1/1; and then its container has a flex display. this works but only for the height, if I scale the width, the flex container and it's content does not scale.
I edited this to be easier to reproduce and used one of the provided solutions which got closest to what I am after.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.game {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header-container {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vh;
  max-height: 100px;
}

.row-container {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  max-height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.square {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  flex: 0 1 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
}

.board-container {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45vh;
}

.lower-container {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  max-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="game">
  <div class="header-container">

  </div>

  <div class="row-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="board-container">

  </div>

  <div class="lower-container">

  </div>
</div>
```

I provided all the css but what i am trying to fix is in .square and .row and .row-container

Comment: Please post a [example].

Comment: I updated the post to have a better reproducible example

Comment: Seems to be working as expected in the snippet. What is missing? Do you want the height and width of each square to be maintained when resizing?

Comment: no once you shrink the height to where the height of the container is smaller than the square, the square does not shrink

Answer (score 1):

```css
#container {
 display: flex;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.square {
 aspect-ratio: 1/1;
 flex: 0 1 55px;
 background-color: blue;
 margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Not quite sure if that's what you are looking for. Can you just provide a brief example of your use-case?

Comment: this seems to work as the width shrinks but as I shrink the height the flex box will get smaller than the squares.

Comment: here is a better example of my use caset his container is sitting inside of a larger container called header-container taking up about 10% of the vertical height of the screen and 100% of the width with a max width of 500px. I had used a flex display on this header-container to keep container in the center of it and maybe that is where my issues are coming from

Comment: I have other containers on the same "level" as my header-container, one small one above it and one below it, I basically just want it so that as the screen size changes and the containers shrink to all be visible the content shrinks while also keeping its aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your question, but are you sure it doesn't scale? Here it is when I set the width to 100%:

```css
#container {
 display: flex;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.square {
 background-color: orange;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 55px;
 aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="square">a</div>
  <div class="square">a</div>
  <div class="square">a</div>
  <div class="square">a</div>
  <div class="square">a</div>
  <div class="square">a</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That didn't quite work, let me explain my usecase a little more since I think I may not have explained the best. this container is sitting inside of a larger container called header-container taking up about 10% of the vertical height of the screen and 100% of the width with a max width of 500px. I had used a flex display on this header-container to keep container in the center of it and maybe that is where my issues are coming from, but if I set width and height to 100% it seems to ignore the aspect ratio and just fills the flex box